# SQL Server 2008 - Spatial MultiLineString problems in creation

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, spatial, multilinestring

I have 3 line string. They are correct but when we try create a `MultiLineString` SQL Server 2008 throws an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not
>   represent a valid geography instance.

I don't see where is the error. Somebody can help me?

```
DECLARE @g3 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-3.3513800000000002 40.49083, -3.3511300000000004 40.49065, -3.3511300000000004 40.49065, -3.35076 40.49078, -3.34947 40.49137, -3.34905 40.49156, -3.3486800000000003 40.491730000000004, -3.3470400000000002 40.49251, -3.3470400000000002 40.49251, -3.3469900000000003 40.492450000000005, -3.34594 40.49123, -3.3452300000000003 40.49034, -3.3451400000000002 40.490230000000004, -3.3450800000000002 40.49015, -3.3450100000000002 40.49007, -3.34498 40.49002, -3.34498 40.49002, -3.345 40.490010000000005, -3.3450100000000002 40.49, -3.3450200000000003 40.48998, -3.3450300000000004 40.48997000000001, -3.3450400000000004 40.48995, -3.3450400000000004 40.48993, -3.3450400000000004 40.489920000000005, -3.3450300000000004 40.489900000000006, -3.3450200000000003 40.48988000000001, -3.3450100000000002 40.48987, -3.34499 40.48986, -3.34498 40.489850000000004, -3.3449500000000003 40.48984, -3.34493 40.48984, -3.3449100000000005 40.489830000000005, -3.3448900000000003 40.48984, -3.3448700000000002 40.48984, -3.3448400000000005 40.489850000000004, -3.3448300000000004 40.48986, -3.3448100000000003 40.48987, -3.3448 40.48988000000001, -3.34479 40.489900000000006, -3.34478 40.489920000000005, -3.34478 40.48993, -3.34478 40.48995, -3.34479 40.48997000000001, -3.3448 40.48998, -3.3448100000000003 40.49, -3.34342 40.49056, -3.3433500000000005 40.490590000000004, -3.3432700000000004 40.49063, -3.34317 40.49069, -3.3430400000000002 40.490790000000004, -3.3427100000000003 40.491020000000006, -3.3423700000000003 40.491240000000005, -3.3409600000000003 40.492270000000005, -3.34037 40.492700000000006, -3.3401600000000004 40.49282, -3.3399500000000004 40.49298, -3.3394800000000004 40.49325, -3.3392600000000003 40.49338, -3.3390700000000004 40.493500000000004, -3.3389300000000004 40.4936, -3.3388600000000004 40.493660000000005, -3.3387700000000002 40.493770000000005, -3.3386700000000004 40.493970000000004, -3.33863 40.49412, -3.3386000000000004 40.49466, -3.33855 40.49486, -3.33849 40.49504, -3.3384000000000005 40.495290000000004, -3.33828 40.495520000000006, -3.3381600000000002 40.49573, -3.3380300000000002 40.49597, -3.3378900000000002 40.49624, -3.3378900000000002 40.49624, -3.3377800000000004 40.49636, -3.33761 40.496500000000005, -3.3374200000000002 40.496640000000006, -3.3371600000000003 40.49685, -3.3369500000000003 40.497020000000006, -3.33637 40.49743, -3.3362700000000003 40.497490000000006, -3.3362200000000004 40.497550000000004, -3.3357900000000002 40.49775, -3.3353200000000003 40.497980000000005, -3.3350800000000005 40.498110000000004, -3.33496 40.49817, -3.3349300000000004 40.498200000000004, -3.3349300000000004 40.49823000000001, -3.3349400000000004 40.498250000000006, -3.3349400000000004 40.498250000000006, -3.33495 40.49826, -3.33496 40.49828, -3.3349800000000002 40.498290000000004, -3.3350100000000004 40.498290000000004, -3.3350500000000003 40.498290000000004, -3.33517 40.498290000000004, -3.33531 40.49833, -3.33543 40.49841, -3.33557 40.498540000000005, -3.33571 40.49868, -3.3357500000000004 40.498720000000006, -3.33578 40.49879000000001, -3.3357900000000002 40.498810000000006, -3.33578 40.498850000000004, -3.33578 40.498850000000004, -3.33577 40.49888, -3.3357300000000003 40.49891, -3.3353800000000002 40.499120000000005, -3.3349300000000004 40.4994, -3.3343100000000003 40.499770000000005, -3.3343100000000003 40.499770000000005, -3.3341600000000002 40.49964000000001, -3.33327 40.500170000000004, -3.33327 40.500170000000004, -3.3316000000000003 40.501160000000006, -3.3316000000000003 40.501160000000006, -3.3313 40.50133)', 4326)
DECLARE @g4 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-3.3313 40.50133, -3.3304300000000002 40.501850000000005, -3.3292100000000002 40.50258, -3.3291000000000004 40.50263, -3.3291000000000004 40.50263, -3.3295200000000005 40.503040000000006, -3.3295200000000005 40.50305, -3.3295200000000005 40.50307, -3.32953 40.503080000000004, -3.32954 40.5031, -3.3295600000000003 40.50311000000001, -3.3295700000000003 40.50312, -3.3295800000000004 40.50312, -3.3296 40.503130000000006, -3.32961 40.503130000000006, -3.33027 40.50377, -3.33027 40.50377, -3.33027 40.503780000000006, -3.3302600000000004 40.503800000000005, -3.33027 40.503820000000005, -3.33027 40.50383, -3.33027 40.503840000000004, -3.33028 40.50386, -3.33029 40.503870000000006, -3.3303100000000003 40.503890000000005, -3.3303200000000004 40.503890000000005, -3.3303300000000004 40.5039, -3.33034 40.5039, -3.33036 40.5039, -3.3303800000000003 40.5039, -3.3303900000000004 40.5039, -3.3304000000000004 40.503890000000005, -3.33041 40.50388, -3.33042 40.503870000000006, -3.3304300000000002 40.50386, -3.3304400000000003 40.50383, -3.3304500000000003 40.503820000000005, -3.3304500000000003 40.503800000000005, -3.3311400000000004 40.503400000000006, -3.3311400000000004 40.503400000000006, -3.33116 40.503420000000005, -3.3312000000000004 40.503440000000005, -3.33123 40.50345, -3.3312700000000004 40.50345, -3.3313200000000003 40.50345, -3.3313500000000004 40.503440000000005, -3.3313900000000003 40.503420000000005, -3.3318600000000002 40.50381, -3.3319300000000003 40.50388, -3.3320200000000004 40.503960000000006, -3.33211 40.50403, -3.3322300000000004 40.50413, -3.3322700000000003 40.50417, -3.3322900000000004 40.504180000000005, -3.33239 40.504270000000005, -3.3326900000000003 40.504490000000004, -3.33313 40.50482, -3.33313 40.50482, -3.33312 40.50477, -3.33306 40.50470000000001, -3.3330300000000004 40.50466, -3.3329700000000004 40.5046, -3.33292 40.50452000000001, -3.3328800000000003 40.504380000000005, -3.33287 40.50424, -3.33287 40.50408, -3.3329100000000005 40.50395, -3.3329400000000002 40.50385, -3.3329700000000004 40.503800000000005, -3.33298 40.503780000000006, -3.3330200000000003 40.503690000000006, -3.3331500000000003 40.503530000000005, -3.33341 40.50336, -3.3350100000000004 40.50235, -3.3354600000000003 40.50207, -3.3358100000000004 40.501920000000005, -3.33604 40.50186, -3.33645 40.50177, -3.33651 40.501760000000004, -3.3371700000000004 40.501630000000006, -3.3373500000000002 40.50159, -3.33754 40.501540000000006, -3.3377200000000004 40.50148, -3.3378400000000003 40.501430000000006, -3.33788 40.50141, -3.33793 40.501380000000005, -3.33801 40.50133, -3.3381200000000004 40.50126, -3.33829 40.50113, -3.3383800000000003 40.50103, -3.33842 40.500980000000005, -3.33854 40.500820000000004, -3.3386500000000003 40.50065, -3.3387900000000003 40.50041, -3.3387900000000003 40.50041, -3.3389300000000004 40.50023, -3.3391800000000002 40.4998, -3.3392500000000002 40.49967, -3.3393100000000002 40.499590000000005, -3.3393900000000003 40.499480000000005, -3.3395 40.49938, -3.3398700000000003 40.499120000000005, -3.3398700000000003 40.499120000000005, -3.3400100000000003 40.499030000000005, -3.3406800000000003 40.49857, -3.34154 40.498000000000005, -3.3416200000000002 40.49795, -3.3417000000000003 40.497890000000005, -3.34174 40.49786, -3.3417700000000003 40.497870000000006, -3.3418300000000003 40.49788, -3.3418900000000002 40.497870000000006, -3.3419100000000004 40.49786, -3.34193 40.497840000000004, -3.34195 40.49781, -3.3419700000000003 40.49777, -3.3419700000000003 40.49772, -3.3429800000000003 40.49709, -3.3438200000000004 40.496550000000006, -3.3448100000000003 40.49591, -3.3449500000000003 40.49582, -3.3452200000000003 40.49564, -3.3459200000000004 40.49519, -3.3461600000000002 40.495050000000006, -3.34641 40.494890000000005, -3.3475 40.494170000000004, -3.3476100000000004 40.4941, -3.3476100000000004 40.4941, -3.34812 40.493770000000005, -3.34824 40.493700000000004, -3.34845 40.4936, -3.34845 40.4936, -3.34846 40.493610000000004, -3.3484800000000003 40.49362, -3.34852 40.49363, -3.3485600000000004 40.493640000000006, -3.34859 40.493640000000006, -3.3486300000000004 40.493640000000006, -3.3486700000000002 40.49363, -3.3489600000000004 40.493880000000004, -3.35002 40.49486, -3.35021 40.495070000000005, -3.3507200000000003 40.49562, -3.3507000000000002 40.495630000000006, -3.35068 40.495650000000005, -3.3506700000000005 40.495670000000004, -3.3506600000000004 40.49570000000001, -3.3506600000000004 40.495720000000006, -3.3506600000000004 40.495740000000005, -3.3506700000000005 40.495760000000004, -3.35068 40.49579000000001, -3.3507000000000002 40.4958, -3.3507200000000003 40.49582, -3.35075 40.495830000000005, -3.3507700000000002 40.49584, -3.3508000000000004 40.495850000000004, -3.35083 40.495850000000004, -3.3508600000000004 40.495850000000004, -3.35089 40.49584, -3.3509200000000003 40.495830000000005, -3.3509900000000003 40.495920000000005, -3.35115 40.496080000000006, -3.35124 40.496190000000006, -3.35142 40.496320000000004, -3.3515900000000003 40.496430000000004, -3.35185 40.496570000000005, -3.3524700000000003 40.496770000000005, -3.3527000000000004 40.4968, -3.3527000000000004 40.4968, -3.3534200000000003 40.496950000000005, -3.35393 40.49705, -3.3540500000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.3540500000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.3540400000000003 40.49709, -3.3540300000000003 40.497110000000006, -3.3540300000000003 40.49712, -3.3540300000000003 40.49714, -3.3540400000000003 40.497150000000005, -3.3540500000000004 40.49716, -3.3540600000000005 40.49718, -3.35407 40.49719, -3.3540900000000002 40.49720000000001, -3.3541100000000003 40.49720000000001, -3.35413 40.49721, -3.35415 40.49721, -3.3541700000000003 40.49721, -3.3541900000000004 40.49720000000001, -3.35421 40.49720000000001, -3.35427 40.49723, -3.3543300000000004 40.497260000000004, -3.3543700000000003 40.49728, -3.3544300000000002 40.49729000000001, -3.35447 40.49729000000001, -3.3545200000000004 40.49729000000001, -3.3545900000000004 40.49728, -3.3546500000000003 40.497260000000004, -3.3547100000000003 40.49723, -3.3547700000000002 40.49720000000001, -3.35482 40.497170000000004, -3.35482 40.497170000000004, -3.3548600000000004 40.49721, -3.3549200000000003 40.49723, -3.3549800000000003 40.497240000000005, -3.3550400000000002 40.497220000000006, -3.35509 40.49719, -3.3551200000000003 40.497150000000005, -3.3556100000000004 40.49712, -3.3563300000000002 40.497060000000005, -3.3569400000000002 40.49698, -3.3579600000000003 40.49674, -3.3589300000000004 40.49653, -3.3592000000000004 40.49647, -3.3596100000000004 40.496370000000006, -3.3598800000000004 40.49631, -3.3601500000000004 40.49624, -3.36052 40.49613, -3.3608300000000004 40.496050000000004, -3.3608300000000004 40.496050000000004, -3.36085 40.49606, -3.3608800000000003 40.49606, -3.3609000000000004 40.49606, -3.36093 40.49606, -3.3609500000000003 40.496050000000004, -3.3609600000000004 40.49604, -3.3609700000000004 40.49602, -3.36098 40.496, -3.36099 40.49598, -3.36098 40.495940000000004, -3.3609700000000004 40.495920000000005, -3.3609500000000003 40.495900000000006, -3.36093 40.49589, -3.3609000000000004 40.49588000000001, -3.3608700000000002 40.49588000000001, -3.36085 40.49589, -3.36079 40.495760000000004, -3.36058 40.49531, -3.3605400000000003 40.495200000000004)', 4326)
DECLARE @g5 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-3.3605400000000003 40.495200000000004, -3.36058 40.49531, -3.36079 40.495760000000004, -3.36085 40.49589, -3.36085 40.49589, -3.3608300000000004 40.495900000000006, -3.3608100000000003 40.495920000000005, -3.3608000000000002 40.49595, -3.3604300000000004 40.49604, -3.3601400000000003 40.496100000000005, -3.35991 40.49616, -3.35964 40.496230000000004, -3.35936 40.496280000000006, -3.3590500000000003 40.496340000000004, -3.3588500000000003 40.49638, -3.3566800000000003 40.496880000000004, -3.35509 40.497020000000006, -3.35509 40.497020000000006, -3.3550400000000002 40.496990000000004, -3.3549800000000003 40.49698, -3.3549200000000003 40.49698, -3.3548600000000004 40.497, -3.35482 40.497040000000005, -3.3548000000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.3547200000000003 40.497130000000006, -3.3546600000000004 40.49716, -3.35461 40.49719, -3.35456 40.49721, -3.3545100000000003 40.49721, -3.3544600000000004 40.497220000000006, -3.3544500000000003 40.497220000000006, -3.3543900000000004 40.49723, -3.3542500000000004 40.49716, -3.3542500000000004 40.49716, -3.3542600000000004 40.497130000000006, -3.3542600000000004 40.4971, -3.3542600000000004 40.49709, -3.3542500000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.3542400000000003 40.497060000000005, -3.35422 40.49705, -3.3542 40.497040000000005, -3.3541900000000004 40.497040000000005, -3.3541700000000003 40.49703, -3.35415 40.49703, -3.35413 40.49703, -3.3541100000000003 40.497040000000005, -3.3540900000000002 40.497040000000005, -3.35407 40.49705, -3.3540600000000005 40.497060000000005, -3.3540500000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.35393 40.49705, -3.3534200000000003 40.496950000000005, -3.3527000000000004 40.4968, -3.3527000000000004 40.4968, -3.3524700000000003 40.496770000000005, -3.35185 40.496570000000005, -3.3515900000000003 40.496430000000004, -3.35142 40.496320000000004, -3.35124 40.496190000000006, -3.35115 40.496080000000006, -3.3509900000000003 40.495920000000005, -3.3509200000000003 40.495830000000005, -3.3509400000000004 40.49582, -3.35096 40.4958, -3.3509800000000003 40.49578, -3.3509900000000003 40.495760000000004, -3.3510000000000004 40.495740000000005, -3.3510000000000004 40.495720000000006, -3.3510000000000004 40.49570000000001, -3.3509900000000003 40.495670000000004, -3.3509800000000003 40.495650000000005, -3.35096 40.495630000000006, -3.3509400000000004 40.49562, -3.3509200000000003 40.4956, -3.35089 40.4956, -3.3508600000000004 40.49559, -3.35083 40.49559, -3.3508000000000004 40.49559, -3.3507700000000002 40.4956, -3.3507400000000005 40.495610000000006, -3.3507200000000003 40.49562, -3.35021 40.495070000000005, -3.35002 40.49486, -3.3489600000000004 40.493880000000004, -3.3486700000000002 40.49363, -3.3486700000000002 40.49363, -3.34871 40.49362, -3.3487400000000002 40.4936, -3.3487700000000004 40.49358, -3.34879 40.49356, -3.3488 40.49353, -3.3488100000000003 40.493500000000004, -3.3488200000000003 40.49347, -3.3488100000000003 40.49344000000001, -3.3488 40.493410000000004, -3.3488 40.4934, -3.3490400000000004 40.493230000000004, -3.34952 40.492940000000004, -3.3495500000000002 40.492920000000005, -3.3498 40.492760000000004, -3.34986 40.492670000000004, -3.34986 40.492670000000004, -3.3505300000000004 40.492230000000006, -3.3508000000000004 40.492050000000006, -3.3512800000000005 40.491760000000006, -3.35137 40.491710000000005, -3.3515300000000003 40.491620000000005, -3.35203 40.4913)', 4326)
declare @g6 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('MultiLineString((-3.3513800000000002 40.49083, -3.3511300000000004 40.49065, -3.3511300000000004 40.49065, -3.35076 40.49078, -3.34947 40.49137, -3.34905 40.49156, -3.3486800000000003 40.491730000000004, -3.3470400000000002 40.49251, -3.3470400000000002 40.49251, -3.3469900000000003 40.492450000000005, -3.34594 40.49123, -3.3452300000000003 40.49034, -3.3451400000000002 40.490230000000004, -3.3450800000000002 40.49015, -3.3450100000000002 40.49007, -3.34498 40.49002, -3.34498 40.49002, -3.345 40.490010000000005, -3.3450100000000002 40.49, -3.3450200000000003 40.48998, -3.3450300000000004 40.48997000000001, -3.3450400000000004 40.48995, -3.3450400000000004 40.48993, -3.3450400000000004 40.489920000000005, -3.3450300000000004 40.489900000000006, -3.3450200000000003 40.48988000000001, -3.3450100000000002 40.48987, -3.34499 40.48986, -3.34498 40.489850000000004, -3.3449500000000003 40.48984, -3.34493 40.48984, -3.3449100000000005 40.489830000000005, -3.3448900000000003 40.48984, -3.3448700000000002 40.48984, -3.3448400000000005 40.489850000000004, -3.3448300000000004 40.48986, -3.3448100000000003 40.48987, -3.3448 40.48988000000001, -3.34479 40.489900000000006, -3.34478 40.489920000000005, -3.34478 40.48993, -3.34478 40.48995, -3.34479 40.48997000000001, -3.3448 40.48998, -3.3448100000000003 40.49, -3.34342 40.49056, -3.3433500000000005 40.490590000000004, -3.3432700000000004 40.49063, -3.34317 40.49069, -3.3430400000000002 40.490790000000004, -3.3427100000000003 40.491020000000006, -3.3423700000000003 40.491240000000005, -3.3409600000000003 40.492270000000005, -3.34037 40.492700000000006, -3.3401600000000004 40.49282, -3.3399500000000004 40.49298, -3.3394800000000004 40.49325, -3.3392600000000003 40.49338, -3.3390700000000004 40.493500000000004, -3.3389300000000004 40.4936, -3.3388600000000004 40.493660000000005, -3.3387700000000002 40.493770000000005, -3.3386700000000004 40.493970000000004, -3.33863 40.49412, -3.3386000000000004 40.49466, -3.33855 40.49486, -3.33849 40.49504, -3.3384000000000005 40.495290000000004, -3.33828 40.495520000000006, -3.3381600000000002 40.49573, -3.3380300000000002 40.49597, -3.3378900000000002 40.49624, -3.3378900000000002 40.49624, -3.3377800000000004 40.49636, -3.33761 40.496500000000005, -3.3374200000000002 40.496640000000006, -3.3371600000000003 40.49685, -3.3369500000000003 40.497020000000006, -3.33637 40.49743, -3.3362700000000003 40.497490000000006, -3.3362200000000004 40.497550000000004, -3.3357900000000002 40.49775, -3.3353200000000003 40.497980000000005, -3.3350800000000005 40.498110000000004, -3.33496 40.49817, -3.3349300000000004 40.498200000000004, -3.3349300000000004 40.49823000000001, -3.3349400000000004 40.498250000000006, -3.3349400000000004 40.498250000000006, -3.33495 40.49826, -3.33496 40.49828, -3.3349800000000002 40.498290000000004, -3.3350100000000004 40.498290000000004, -3.3350500000000003 40.498290000000004, -3.33517 40.498290000000004, -3.33531 40.49833, -3.33543 40.49841, -3.33557 40.498540000000005, -3.33571 40.49868, -3.3357500000000004 40.498720000000006, -3.33578 40.49879000000001, -3.3357900000000002 40.498810000000006, -3.33578 40.498850000000004, -3.33578 40.498850000000004, -3.33577 40.49888, -3.3357300000000003 40.49891, -3.3353800000000002 40.499120000000005, -3.3349300000000004 40.4994, -3.3343100000000003 40.499770000000005, -3.3343100000000003 40.499770000000005, -3.3341600000000002 40.49964000000001, -3.33327 40.500170000000004, -3.33327 40.500170000000004, -3.3316000000000003 40.501160000000006, -3.3316000000000003 40.501160000000006, -3.3313 40.50133),(-3.3313 40.50133, -3.3304300000000002 40.501850000000005, -3.3292100000000002 40.50258, -3.3291000000000004 40.50263, -3.3291000000000004 40.50263, -3.3295200000000005 40.503040000000006, -3.3295200000000005 40.50305, -3.3295200000000005 40.50307, -3.32953 40.503080000000004, -3.32954 40.5031, -3.3295600000000003 40.50311000000001, -3.3295700000000003 40.50312, -3.3295800000000004 40.50312, -3.3296 40.503130000000006, -3.32961 40.503130000000006, -3.33027 40.50377, -3.33027 40.50377, -3.33027 40.503780000000006, -3.3302600000000004 40.503800000000005, -3.33027 40.503820000000005, -3.33027 40.50383, -3.33027 40.503840000000004, -3.33028 40.50386, -3.33029 40.503870000000006, -3.3303100000000003 40.503890000000005, -3.3303200000000004 40.503890000000005, -3.3303300000000004 40.5039, -3.33034 40.5039, -3.33036 40.5039, -3.3303800000000003 40.5039, -3.3303900000000004 40.5039, -3.3304000000000004 40.503890000000005, -3.33041 40.50388, -3.33042 40.503870000000006, -3.3304300000000002 40.50386, -3.3304400000000003 40.50383, -3.3304500000000003 40.503820000000005, -3.3304500000000003 40.503800000000005, -3.3311400000000004 40.503400000000006, -3.3311400000000004 40.503400000000006, -3.33116 40.503420000000005, -3.3312000000000004 40.503440000000005, -3.33123 40.50345, -3.3312700000000004 40.50345, -3.3313200000000003 40.50345, -3.3313500000000004 40.503440000000005, -3.3313900000000003 40.503420000000005, -3.3318600000000002 40.50381, -3.3319300000000003 40.50388, -3.3320200000000004 40.503960000000006, -3.33211 40.50403, -3.3322300000000004 40.50413, -3.3322700000000003 40.50417, -3.3322900000000004 40.504180000000005, -3.33239 40.504270000000005, -3.3326900000000003 40.504490000000004, -3.33313 40.50482, -3.33313 40.50482, -3.33312 40.50477, -3.33306 40.50470000000001, -3.3330300000000004 40.50466, -3.3329700000000004 40.5046, -3.33292 40.50452000000001, -3.3328800000000003 40.504380000000005, -3.33287 40.50424, -3.33287 40.50408, -3.3329100000000005 40.50395, -3.3329400000000002 40.50385, -3.3329700000000004 40.503800000000005, -3.33298 40.503780000000006, -3.3330200000000003 40.503690000000006, -3.3331500000000003 40.503530000000005, -3.33341 40.50336, -3.3350100000000004 40.50235, -3.3354600000000003 40.50207, -3.3358100000000004 40.501920000000005, -3.33604 40.50186, -3.33645 40.50177, -3.33651 40.501760000000004, -3.3371700000000004 40.501630000000006, -3.3373500000000002 40.50159, -3.33754 40.501540000000006, -3.3377200000000004 40.50148, -3.3378400000000003 40.501430000000006, -3.33788 40.50141, -3.33793 40.501380000000005, -3.33801 40.50133, -3.3381200000000004 40.50126, -3.33829 40.50113, -3.3383800000000003 40.50103, -3.33842 40.500980000000005, -3.33854 40.500820000000004, -3.3386500000000003 40.50065, -3.3387900000000003 40.50041, -3.3387900000000003 40.50041, -3.3389300000000004 40.50023, -3.3391800000000002 40.4998, -3.3392500000000002 40.49967, -3.3393100000000002 40.499590000000005, -3.3393900000000003 40.499480000000005, -3.3395 40.49938, -3.3398700000000003 40.499120000000005, -3.3398700000000003 40.499120000000005, -3.3400100000000003 40.499030000000005, -3.3406800000000003 40.49857, -3.34154 40.498000000000005, -3.3416200000000002 40.49795, -3.3417000000000003 40.497890000000005, -3.34174 40.49786, -3.3417700000000003 40.497870000000006, -3.3418300000000003 40.49788, -3.3418900000000002 40.497870000000006, -3.3419100000000004 40.49786, -3.34193 40.497840000000004, -3.34195 40.49781, -3.3419700000000003 40.49777, -3.3419700000000003 40.49772, -3.3429800000000003 40.49709, -3.3438200000000004 40.496550000000006, -3.3448100000000003 40.49591, -3.3449500000000003 40.49582, -3.3452200000000003 40.49564, -3.3459200000000004 40.49519, -3.3461600000000002 40.495050000000006, -3.34641 40.494890000000005, -3.3475 40.494170000000004, -3.3476100000000004 40.4941, -3.3476100000000004 40.4941, -3.34812 40.493770000000005, -3.34824 40.493700000000004, -3.34845 40.4936, -3.34845 40.4936, -3.34846 40.493610000000004, -3.3484800000000003 40.49362, -3.34852 40.49363, -3.3485600000000004 40.493640000000006, -3.34859 40.493640000000006, -3.3486300000000004 40.493640000000006, -3.3486700000000002 40.49363, -3.3489600000000004 40.493880000000004, -3.35002 40.49486, -3.35021 40.495070000000005, -3.3507200000000003 40.49562, -3.3507000000000002 40.495630000000006, -3.35068 40.495650000000005, -3.3506700000000005 40.495670000000004, -3.3506600000000004 40.49570000000001, -3.3506600000000004 40.495720000000006, -3.3506600000000004 40.495740000000005, -3.3506700000000005 40.495760000000004, -3.35068 40.49579000000001, -3.3507000000000002 40.4958, -3.3507200000000003 40.49582, -3.35075 40.495830000000005, -3.3507700000000002 40.49584, -3.3508000000000004 40.495850000000004, -3.35083 40.495850000000004, -3.3508600000000004 40.495850000000004, -3.35089 40.49584, -3.3509200000000003 40.495830000000005, -3.3509900000000003 40.495920000000005, -3.35115 40.496080000000006, -3.35124 40.496190000000006, -3.35142 40.496320000000004, -3.3515900000000003 40.496430000000004, -3.35185 40.496570000000005, -3.3524700000000003 40.496770000000005, -3.3527000000000004 40.4968, -3.3527000000000004 40.4968, -3.3534200000000003 40.496950000000005, -3.35393 40.49705, -3.3540500000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.3540500000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.3540400000000003 40.49709, -3.3540300000000003 40.497110000000006, -3.3540300000000003 40.49712, -3.3540300000000003 40.49714, -3.3540400000000003 40.497150000000005, -3.3540500000000004 40.49716, -3.3540600000000005 40.49718, -3.35407 40.49719, -3.3540900000000002 40.49720000000001, -3.3541100000000003 40.49720000000001, -3.35413 40.49721, -3.35415 40.49721, -3.3541700000000003 40.49721, -3.3541900000000004 40.49720000000001, -3.35421 40.49720000000001, -3.35427 40.49723, -3.3543300000000004 40.497260000000004, -3.3543700000000003 40.49728, -3.3544300000000002 40.49729000000001, -3.35447 40.49729000000001, -3.3545200000000004 40.49729000000001, -3.3545900000000004 40.49728, -3.3546500000000003 40.497260000000004, -3.3547100000000003 40.49723, -3.3547700000000002 40.49720000000001, -3.35482 40.497170000000004, -3.35482 40.497170000000004, -3.3548600000000004 40.49721, -3.3549200000000003 40.49723, -3.3549800000000003 40.497240000000005, -3.3550400000000002 40.497220000000006, -3.35509 40.49719, -3.3551200000000003 40.497150000000005, -3.3556100000000004 40.49712, -3.3563300000000002 40.497060000000005, -3.3569400000000002 40.49698, -3.3579600000000003 40.49674, -3.3589300000000004 40.49653, -3.3592000000000004 40.49647, -3.3596100000000004 40.496370000000006, -3.3598800000000004 40.49631, -3.3601500000000004 40.49624, -3.36052 40.49613, -3.3608300000000004 40.496050000000004, -3.3608300000000004 40.496050000000004, -3.36085 40.49606, -3.3608800000000003 40.49606, -3.3609000000000004 40.49606, -3.36093 40.49606, -3.3609500000000003 40.496050000000004, -3.3609600000000004 40.49604, -3.3609700000000004 40.49602, -3.36098 40.496, -3.36099 40.49598, -3.36098 40.495940000000004, -3.3609700000000004 40.495920000000005, -3.3609500000000003 40.495900000000006, -3.36093 40.49589, -3.3609000000000004 40.49588000000001, -3.3608700000000002 40.49588000000001, -3.36085 40.49589, -3.36079 40.495760000000004, -3.36058 40.49531, -3.3605400000000003 40.495200000000004),(-3.3605400000000003 40.495200000000004, -3.36058 40.49531, -3.36079 40.495760000000004, -3.36085 40.49589, -3.36085 40.49589, -3.3608300000000004 40.495900000000006, -3.3608100000000003 40.495920000000005, -3.3608000000000002 40.49595, -3.3604300000000004 40.49604, -3.3601400000000003 40.496100000000005, -3.35991 40.49616, -3.35964 40.496230000000004, -3.35936 40.496280000000006, -3.3590500000000003 40.496340000000004, -3.3588500000000003 40.49638, -3.3566800000000003 40.496880000000004, -3.35509 40.497020000000006, -3.35509 40.497020000000006, -3.3550400000000002 40.496990000000004, -3.3549800000000003 40.49698, -3.3549200000000003 40.49698, -3.3548600000000004 40.497, -3.35482 40.497040000000005, -3.3548000000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.3547200000000003 40.497130000000006, -3.3546600000000004 40.49716, -3.35461 40.49719, -3.35456 40.49721, -3.3545100000000003 40.49721, -3.3544600000000004 40.497220000000006, -3.3544500000000003 40.497220000000006, -3.3543900000000004 40.49723, -3.3542500000000004 40.49716, -3.3542500000000004 40.49716, -3.3542600000000004 40.497130000000006, -3.3542600000000004 40.4971, -3.3542600000000004 40.49709, -3.3542500000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.3542400000000003 40.497060000000005, -3.35422 40.49705, -3.3542 40.497040000000005, -3.3541900000000004 40.497040000000005, -3.3541700000000003 40.49703, -3.35415 40.49703, -3.35413 40.49703, -3.3541100000000003 40.497040000000005, -3.3540900000000002 40.497040000000005, -3.35407 40.49705, -3.3540600000000005 40.497060000000005, -3.3540500000000004 40.497080000000004, -3.35393 40.49705, -3.3534200000000003 40.496950000000005, -3.3527000000000004 40.4968, -3.3527000000000004 40.4968, -3.3524700000000003 40.496770000000005, -3.35185 40.496570000000005, -3.3515900000000003 40.496430000000004, -3.35142 40.496320000000004, -3.35124 40.496190000000006, -3.35115 40.496080000000006, -3.3509900000000003 40.495920000000005, -3.3509200000000003 40.495830000000005, -3.3509400000000004 40.49582, -3.35096 40.4958, -3.3509800000000003 40.49578, -3.3509900000000003 40.495760000000004, -3.3510000000000004 40.495740000000005, -3.3510000000000004 40.495720000000006, -3.3510000000000004 40.49570000000001, -3.3509900000000003 40.495670000000004, -3.3509800000000003 40.495650000000005, -3.35096 40.495630000000006, -3.3509400000000004 40.49562, -3.3509200000000003 40.4956, -3.35089 40.4956, -3.3508600000000004 40.49559, -3.35083 40.49559, -3.3508000000000004 40.49559, -3.3507700000000002 40.4956, -3.3507400000000005 40.495610000000006, -3.3507200000000003 40.49562, -3.35021 40.495070000000005, -3.35002 40.49486, -3.3489600000000004 40.493880000000004, -3.3486700000000002 40.49363, -3.3486700000000002 40.49363, -3.34871 40.49362, -3.3487400000000002 40.4936, -3.3487700000000004 40.49358, -3.34879 40.49356, -3.3488 40.49353, -3.3488100000000003 40.493500000000004, -3.3488200000000003 40.49347, -3.3488100000000003 40.49344000000001, -3.3488 40.493410000000004, -3.3488 40.4934, -3.3490400000000004 40.493230000000004, -3.34952 40.492940000000004, -3.3495500000000002 40.492920000000005, -3.3498 40.492760000000004, -3.34986 40.492670000000004, -3.34986 40.492670000000004, -3.3505300000000004 40.492230000000006, -3.3508000000000004 40.492050000000006, -3.3512800000000005 40.491760000000006, -3.35137 40.491710000000005, -3.3515300000000003 40.491620000000005, -3.35203 40.4913))', 4326)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error's somewhere in your G6 line. Something about the 2nd and 3rd linestrings you're defining fails - possibly both have a segment in common that overlaps, which is not permitted.

Comment: The problem is with linestring g4 and g5. You tell me that the problem is with a overlap. If I check msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895166.aspx and I check the figures, there are some multilinestring with overloads....

Answer (score 0):

I read again the msdn. You are right.***2.No two LineString instances comprising the MultiLineString instance may overlap over an interval***

So may be the solution to the problem is store this data as multipoint, but if we choose this option, we'll have a problem with STDistance. The result is different if you save as multilinestring or multipoint.

The solution is use a GEOMETRY COLLECTION!

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark an answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn.  Cheers~